# VS 2008, MFC: add OnInitDialog - how?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, ide, mfc

This is my first MFC application away from VC6, and I feel a little bit stupid:

How do I add the OnInitDialog handler?
(I know how to add it manually, but that's a pain in the long run).

double-clicking the dialog - nothing.
right click the dialog - "add event handler" is disabled.
Properties - Messages has "normal" messages, but not WM_INITDIALOG
Properties - Events only holds notifications from contained controls
right-clicking in class view - "Add.." only has functions and variables

*scratches head*

[edit] d'oh - it's a virtual function in MFC, but still...

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Don't feel stupid, it took me forever to figure this out when I first moved from VC6 to VS2008!

Anyway, and also for my own reference, here are the complete steps for adding a dialog box and overriding the `OnInitDialog` method:

1. Select **Resource View** and expand the .rc file.
2. Right-click the **Dialog** entry in the tree view and select **Insert Dialog**.
3. Select the **Properties** window. (Note: If you don't see this window, select the **View** > **Other Windows** > **Properties Window** menu item.)
4. In the **Properties** window, set the ID for the dialog, e.g., `IDD_MYDIALOG`.
5. Right click the dialog in the resource editor and select **Add Class**. Note: if you have IE8 installed, this may produce an Internet Explorer Script Error. See [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/vcblog/archive/2009/03/28/some-vs2005-and-vs2008-wizards-pop-up-script-error.aspx) for details on how to correct this.
6. In the **MFC Class Wizard** dialog box, enter the class name, e.g., `CMyDialog`, select `CDialog` as the base class, then press **Finish**. This will create files named `MyDialog.cpp` and `MyDialog.h` and add them to your project.

To override the `OnInitDialog` method in the `CMyDialog` class:

1. Open the file `MyDialog.h`.
2. Select the **Properties** window.
3. Place the cursor on the line that reads `class CMyDialog : public CDialog`. (The top of the Properties window should show "**CMyDialog** VCCodeClass" - this is important, because the **Properties** window is highly context sensitive, and you get different options depending on the location of the cursor in the editor.)
4. Click the **Overrides** icon in the **Properties** window.
5. Scroll down the properties window to find `OnInitDialog`.
6. Click the down arrow against this entry and select **<Add> OnInitDialog**. This should create your `CMyDialog::OnInitDialog` function.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Just wanted to mention that this eluded me for a very long time as well after I migrated to VS2008 from VC6. It can take a bit of getting used to.

Comment: Found it!  :-D

It always helps to know you are not alone.

Comment: In step 5, "Add Class" is disabled. !!

Answer (score 4):

It appears that you don't even have to open the header file and mess around placing the cursor... After creatingthe class, select the class in the ClassView pane and you can change overrides/messages/events in the Property pane as described above.

Comment: Because it is not required to open the header file and mess around with positioning the cursor on the correct line of code to get the properties pane to display correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Open Class Wizard, then go to Virtual Functions Tab.
Double Click on which functions you want to override