# How to fix row and column repetition in CListctrl

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, clistctrl

[image]

How to fix row and column repetition in CListctrl in MFC.

```
int nItem = 0;
m_list.InsertColumn(0, _T("Name"), LVCFMT_LEFT, 100);
m_list.InsertColumn(1, _T("Area km\262"), LVCFMT_RIGHT, 80);
m_list.InsertColumn(2, _T("Population"), LVCFMT_RIGHT, 100);
m_list.SetExtendedStyle(LVS_EX_GRIDLINES | LVS_EX_FULLROWSELECT);
ModifyStyle(0, LVS_REPORT);

nItem = m_list.InsertItem(0, _T("Libya"), 8);
m_list.SetItemText(nItem, 1, _T("1,759,540"));
m_list.SetItemText(nItem, 2, _T("5,499,074"));

nItem = m_list.InsertItem(0, _T("Senegal"), 7);
m_list.SetItemText(nItem, 1, _T("196,190"));
m_list.SetItemText(nItem, 2,_T( "10,580,307"));

nItem = m_list.InsertItem(0, _T("Cuba"), 6);
m_list.SetItemText(nItem, 1, _T("110,860"));
m_list.SetItemText(nItem, 2, _T("11,263,429"));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it not that you're simply not clearing the list before refreshing the contents. And it's appending rows and columns again rather than replacing. Call [`m_list.DeleteAllItems()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x47efeht.aspx) before refreshing.

---

*Update after comment:*

Right, so that confirms you're refreshing the contents too often or in the wrong place. `DeleteAllItems()` will clear the contents, not remove column headers already added.

So either (1) call [`DeleteColumn()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75edh5fy.aspx) on each of the already inserted columns first, or (2) preferably do the inserting of columns in a more appropriate place where it'll only happen once. Say in the [OnInitDialog()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/961617/vs-2008-mfc-add-oninitdialog-how) of the dialog I presume you're working with.

Comment: By using function row item is not repeating But for column problem is same.

Answer (score 3):

`CListCtrl` does not care if your item should be unique or not. So you have to handle it yourself.

You need to create and use `std::map` or even `std::set` structure for items that should be unique and do a lookup each time you need to insert an item or a column:

**Insert:**

```
std::set<CString> listItems;
listItems.insert(columnName);
```

**Lookup:**

```
const bool is_in = listItems.find(element) != listItems.end();
```

You can also use `CMap` MFC container to do that.